# jquery,javascript,html div related query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I want to create two divs (left and right). If a link is clicked on left it should open the data in the right div and in the right div there are multiple questions. Each question is clickable and it shows answers on click. I have implemented this but when a question opens the previous question won't close and I want it to close. I have used toggle which closes the same link.

My code is as follows:

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('.show').click(function () {
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
});

$('.innerdiv').hide();
$('.answer').click(function(){
    $('#innerdiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();   
});
```

```
<html>
    <div style="width: 30%; float:left">
        <div class="buttons">
            <ul>
                <li><a  class="show" target="1">Placing an Order</a></li>
                <li><a  class="show" target="2">blah.com Returns & Cancellations FAQs</a></li>
                <li><a  class="show" target="3">Brands & Stock</a></li>
                <li><a  class="show" target="4">Shipping & Delivery</a></li>
                <li><a  class="show" target="5">Payment</a></li>
                <li><a  class="show" target="6">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a  class="show" target="7">Value Added Tax (VAT)</a></li>
                <li><a  class="show" target="8">Privacy & Security</a></li>
                <li><a  class="show" target="9">About the Company</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 70%; float:right">
        <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="answer" target="1">I need personal assistance with my order. Who can I contact?</a>
                    <div id="innerdiv1" class="innerdiv" >Our customer service centre is happy to assist you with your order on +91 124 6733300 (10 AM - 7 PM)</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="answer" target="2" >How do I start a new account?</a>
                    <div id="innerdiv2" class="innerdiv">blah blah </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="answer" target="3">I am having problems ordering through your website. What can I do?</a>
                    <div id="innerdiv3" class="innerdiv"> hahahahah </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="answer" target="4" >I need personal assistance with my order. Who can I contact?</a>
                    <div id="innerdiv4" class="innerdiv"> b;la ablahhap </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="answer" target="5" >How do I start a new account?</a>
                    <div id="innerdiv5" class="innerdiv">blah blah </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>​
</html>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C59bE/8/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the `innerdiv`s

```
$('.answer').click(function(){
    var $target = $('#innerdiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();   
    $('.targetDiv .innerdiv').not($target).hide()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xx6NR/)

Comment: This hinders the function of toggle. Toggle is not working in this condition.

Comment: @user3239364 missed that :( .... fixed